# Using gmake to build large system

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on trying to fix/redo the makefile(s) for a legacy system, and I keep banging my head against some things. This is a **huge** software system, consisting of numerous executables, shared objects, and libraries, using C, Fortran, and a couple of other compilers (such as Motif's UIL compiler). I'm trying to avoid recursive `make` and I would prefer "one makefile to build them all" rather than the existing "one makefile per executable/.so/.a" idea. (We call each executable, shared object, library, *et al* a "task," so permit me to use that term as I go forward.)

The system is scattered across tons of different source subdirectories, with includes **usually** in one of 6 main directories, though not always.

What would be the best way to deal with the plethora of source & target directories? I would prefer including a Task.mk file for each task that would provide the task-specific details, but target-specific variables don't give me enough control. For example, they don't allow me to change the source & target directories easily, at least from what I've tried.

Some things I **cannot** (*i.e.*, not allowed to) do include:

- Change the structure of the project. There's too much that would need to be changed everywhere to pull that off.
- Use a different `make`. The official configuration (which our customer has guaranteed, so we don't need to deal with unknown configurations) uses gmake 3.81, period.

Comment: First off: Good luck. If this build is anything like many of the builds that exist in the world this is going to be a painful process as things will be fragile, poorly connected, under-specified, etc. Does the current build setup work? Does it work with `-j#` specified (reliably)? Do you have a verbose log of a good current build?

Comment: Yes, @EtanReisner, I knew this job was dangerous when I took it. :) The current build setup works, but it knows absolutely **nothing** about dependencies (not even .h files!), consists of over a dozen nested make files that are impossible to maintain, and each task has to be built separately. It also defaults to build-then-clean, meaning you can't even reuse the results of a previous build. To build the whole thing, there are a series of shell scripts that are kicked off sequentially (so, no, `-j#` cannot work well).

Comment: Not a single bit of that makes any of this easier. And, in fact, makes it all *much* harder. Because, if you expect this to work correctly, you need to ensure you get **all** that right yourself and if you don't your build breaks in subtle and mysterious ways.

Comment: Oh, and I've got partial dumps from representative sample tasks, so I have some clue of what's needed. Security restrictions prevent me from posting any of it, though.

Comment: Correct, @EtanReisner. The current mess, though, is impossible to enhance, even to get dependencies to work. Just as an example of this mess, one "task" actually has 3 different makefiles: one for a static archive (because "that's how we did it before" under OpenVMS), one for UIL compilation, and one for the final executable. Each one of those includes a different sequence of "generic" makefiles to do its job. To build it, you have to know what other archives to make, do those, then invoke make with the 3 different files.

Comment: To add further injury, one part of the "generic" makefiles is surrounded by `ifdef WHATTHEHELL`.

Comment: Nice. I don't doubt, for even an instant, that you have very good reasons to want to make this better. But this is an area full of "it looks better until something goes horribly wrong and possibly in a near-to or completely silent way that no one notices for a while". The first thing to do should probably be to actually gather all that dependency information (and figure out how much of it is static and how much of it is dynamic/can be generated from the sources/etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66063/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-joe-sewell).

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66063/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-joe-sewell).

Comment: Chat room is closed, but a quick status update: I've been inspired by ImageMagick's final makefile that this **can** be done. My current thinking is to have a bootstrap makefile that will load information from other files and construct the final makefile. Target-specific variables and secondary expansion doesn't look like it will be enough.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309714/issue-with-make-file-with-files-in-multiple-directories/28318083#28318083

Comment: Saw that, @Bulletmagnet, but even that doesn't completely handle this situation, since target files are also all over the place.

Comment: @JoeSewell Maybe you can change that.