# Issue with Make file with files in multiple directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the below make file. This was working fine when I had files only in one directory which is SOURCEDIR. Now I added PROTOSOURCES and PROTOSRCDIR.

I will be executing the makefile in SRCDIR.

```
VERSION = 0.0.1
CC      = /usr/bin/g++
CFLAGS  = -Wall
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`
SHFLAGS = -shared
SOURCEDIR = .
PROTOSRCDIR = ~/depot/Projects/src1/obj/cpp
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
PROTOSOURCES = $(wildcard $(PROTOSRCDIR)/*.cc)
SRCOBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp, $(SOURCEDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
PROTOOBJECTS = $(patsubst $(PROTOSRCDIR)/%.cc, $(PROTOSRCDIR)/%.o, $(PROTOSOURCES))

LIBRARY = libprotointf.so

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(LIBRARY)

$(LIBRARY): 
    $(CC) $(SHFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRCOBJECTS) $(PROTOOBJECTS) -o    $(LIBRARY)

$(SOURCEDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c -fPIC $< -o $@

$(PROTOSRCDIR)/%.o: $(PROTOSRCDIR)/%.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c -fPIC $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f libprotointf.so
```

I am having below issues.

Issue 1: The SOURCEOBJECTS is as expected and lists all the object files in SOURCEDIR. However the PROTOOBJECTS just list *.cc files instead of *.o files. I expect it to have all the list of object files in PROTOOBJECTS after the use with patsubst. Btw, SOURCEDIR has *.cpp files where as PROTOSRCDIR has .pb.cc files. These are generated by Google Protocol Buffer compiler.

Issue 2:
This will be the final goal of my make file.
1) Compile the files in SRCDIR & generate the .o files
2) Compile the files in PROTOSRCDIR & generate the .o files
3) generate a shared library libprotointf.so file with all the objects files from above two steps.

My Library linking and compiling commands are as below when I had files only in SRCDIR, which works fine.

```
$(LIBRARY): 
    $(CC) $(SHFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRCOBJECTS) -o $(LIBRARY)
$(SOURCEDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -c -fPIC $< -o $@
```

What are the modifications that i need to do to my Makefile in order to make the shared library ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to those variables. It's probably related to the fact that you haven't listed `$(SRCOBJECTS) $(PROTOOBJECTS)` as prerequisites of `$(LIBRARY)`.

Comment: Not related to your problem but you don't need `$(SOURCEDIR)` and `$(PROTOSRCDIR)` in the `$(patsubst)` calls you can just have them swallowed as part of the `%` wildcard. So `SRCOBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, $%.o, $(SOURCES))` for example.

Comment: Don't use `~` use `$HOME`. `~` is a shell thing and the shell isn't involved in expanding `$(PROTOSRCDIR)` anywhere.

Comment: Similarly your assignment of `LDFLAGS` isn't being executed when you assign it. (It will be executed when used in a recipe line because the shell will see the backticks and run the command but that's not necessarily when you want that happening.) For make-parse-time running of commands you need to use `$(shell)` (and the `:=` simply-expanded variable assignment to have make only do it once at parse time instead of once each time the variable is used).

Comment: And seconding what @user657267 said in their comment the `$(LIBRARY)` target doesn't tell make to build the objects that it needs to link with so make doesn't do that for you. So even your previous makefile should only have been working if you pre-built all the `.o` files. Remove them and it should have failed to link.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. With Etan Reisner, i could solve Issue 1. Issue 2 also I solved in little different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `VPATH` feature of make. This tells make to look for "sources" in other directories too. All the object files would end up in the build directory, along with the shared library.

```
# Note: GNU make syntax
VERSION := 0.0.1
CXX     := /usr/bin/g++
CXXFLAGS:= -Wall -fPIC
LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)
SHFLAGS := -shared
SOURCEDIR := .
PROTOSRCDIR := ~/depot/Projects/src1/obj/cpp

VPATH := $(SOURCEDIR):$(PROTOSRCDIR)

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp) # full paths
SOURCEFILES := $(notdir $(SOURCES)) # just (source) filenames
OBJECTS := $(SOURCEFILES:.cpp=.o) # all in the current dir

PROTOSOURCES = $(wildcard $(PROTOSRCDIR)/*.cc) # full paths
PROTOSOURCEFILES := $(notdir $(PROTOSOURCES)) # just (source) filenames
PROTOOBJECTS := $(PROTOSOURCEFILES:.cpp=.o) # all in the current dir

LIBRARY = libprotointf.so

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(LIBRARY)

$(LIBRARY): $(OBJECTS) $(PROTOOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(SHFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Note: there is no `%.o: %.cc` or  `%.o: %.cpp` rule. GNU make has these built in. All you need to is fill in values for `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`

Note that by convention, `CC` is the variable containing the C compiler. The variable of the C++ compiler is `CXX`. Similarly, `CFLAGS` is for the C compiler; `CXXFLAGS` is the variable containing flags for the C++ compiler.

How this works:

Assuming you have s1.cpp and s2.cpp in SOURCEDIR and p1.pb.cc, p2.pb.cc in PROTOSRCDIR, libprotoinf.so depends on s1.o, s2.o, p1.pb.o, p2.pb.o

Make can easily build s1.o from s1.cpp and s2.o from s2.cpp using its built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule. When it tries to build p1.pb.o, it won't find p1.pb.cc in the current directory, but the VPATH variable tells it to also look in PROTOSRCDIR. Then make will build p1.pb.o from $(PROTOSRCDIR)/p1.pb.cc, as if the cc file was present in the current directory.

With this technique, you can even build in a separate build directory which is different from SOURCEDIR.