# Why does flock deadlock in this bash code?

Tags: bash, makefile, flock

This is probably a stupid question, but I just don't see it.

I'm creating a `gmake` makefile to build our system, as noted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256777/using-gmake-to-build-large-system). I want the makefile to be able to build both debug and release versions simultaneously (perhaps a big mistake, but let's keep that separate). The tricky part, as always, is building the dependencies. Right now I'm having both versions rebuild the dependency files, and using `sed` to make each dependency file work with both debug & release versions.

The code resembles the following:

```
(flock 200 ; umask 002 ; $(FORTRAN) $(STD_FOR_OPTS) -O2 \
 -gen-dep=$(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d $(INCLUDEPATH) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ ; \
 sed -e [stuff to remove a pesky abberent line] \
     -i $(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d; \
 flock -s 200 ; flock -x 201 ; cp $(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d $(task_DEPDIR)$(<F).d; \
 sed -e [fairly standard dependency editing per various sources] \
     < $(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d >> $(task_DEPDIR)$(<F).d; \
 rm -f $(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d) \
200>$(task_SRCDIR)$(<F).d 201>$(task_DEPDIR)$(<F).d
```

(The `-gen-dep` option is from the Intel compiler suite we must use.)

Everything works out find, normally. The `sed` commands do the proper editing, and all is right with the world ... except for the rare, unpredictable case where a deadlock occurs. This code is run for both debug (albeit with `-g -debug` instead of `-O2`) and release versions using static pattern rules and absolute directories.

If I invoke the makefile with `make -j 4 all` I get both `flock 200` statements (**not** `flock -s 200` according to a `ps -O cmd`) stalled simultaneously, as if there's a kernel-level race condition between the two. The invoking shells are targeting the same `.d` files, which makes sense as they'd be the only two that should be using them. I don't get, though, why one `flock 200` isn't getting granted, but both are blocking.

All files are on the same local filesystem; no NFS flakiness is involved (at least not at the moment).

Ignoring the obvious decisions to do dependencies differently (which I'm looking at anyhow for this situation), using templates (another consideration for later), etc., how can the `flock 200` be deadlocking here?

**EDIT** I just read the following [here](http://jdimpson.livejournal.com/5685.html):

> Finally, if a locked file gets deleted, subsequent lock attempts will succeed even if something is holding an old lock. So if you're protecting access to an arbitrary resource, be aware of the access control permissions of the lock file. You don't want anyone to delete the file from under you.

Perhaps I should explicitly `flock -u 200` after the `rm ...`?

Comment: is the partition you are locking on nfs or some other non-local kind of disk?

Comment: Good point, @frankc. At the moment, no, everything's on a local `ext3` filesystem. This **will** be used, however, in a Clearcase/MVFS environment where view-private files would indeed be housed on a networked drive. I think the question is still valid, but you've talked me into bailing on this strategy. I've updated the question to address your comment. Thanks!