# gmake ignores files dependent on -include files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In an effort to replace the mess of independent makefiles we inherited from another project with something that actually uses `make` as it should be (as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256777/using-gmake-to-build-large-system), I've come across a rather unusual situation in which `gmake 3.81` ignores files it cannot generate nor can find.

Here's a short sample file that demonstrates the problem:

```
# Remove ALL default rules
.SUFFIXES:
(%): %
%.out: %
%.c: %.w %.ch
%.tex: %.w %.ch
%:: %.v
%:: RCS/%,v
%:: RCS/%
%:: s.%
%:: SCCS/s.%

SOURCES = a.c b.c

OBJS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

DEPFILES = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.c.d)

EXE = a

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE)

$(DEPFILES): %.c.d : %.c
        @echo "Determining dependencies for $(<F)"
        @$(CC) -E -MM -MF$@ -MP $<

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
        @echo "Compiling $(<F)"
        @$(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
        @echo "Linking $(@F)"
        @$(CC) $+ -o $@

# This seems to be the troublemaking line!
-include $(DEPFILES)
```

If one or more of the source files is missing, the corresponding `.d` file is not made, as expected, **but** the source file is not flagged as missing. If I run this with a simple `make` command, **nothing** is output, and the exit status is 2.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Oh, although it seems silly in this example, I do have several restrictions in this project:

- We **must** use `gmake 3.81`. No upgrading or patching allowed.
- The full makefile builds both a debug & a release version, so dependencies are generated separately, once for all. It turned out to be simpler that way.
- Using static pattern rules seems silly here, but in the large makefile it solves many problems.
- The actual generation of dependencies is significantly more complex in the real system, using a Perl script I wrote to massage the equivalent output of the Intel compiler suite (again, a requirement) into something useful.
- I've thought about pre-testing the existence of every file, but not all of them are known until the dependency files are generated. As it stands, with just this one file and nothing else in a directory, **no** shell commands get executed.

Comment: `all : $(DEPFILES) $(EXE)` maybe? Force the dependency files to be prerequisites for something else, not just a `-include` directive, which by definition ignores non-existence of the named files.

Comment: That might work for this simplified example, but finding out where to add the prerequisite in a complex makefile with potentially dozens of different targets may not be as easy.

Comment: @JoeSewell  consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to help you to interactively determine where prerequisites might go.

Comment: I'd love to, @rocky, but we aren't allowed to add unapproved software. Besides, the output of `make -d` shows make is likely ignoring prerequisites of `-include` files and forgetting to note that for proper target-prerequisite relationships. If I were allowed, I'd check if this were fixed in 4.1, but, again, it's a security no-no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in gmake 3.81 and later, related to [this bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?29074). I've reported [this specific bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45438), as it is slightly different.

The workaround I've chosen to use is inspired by the above link, is noted below:

```
# Remove ALL default rules
.SUFFIXES:
(%): %
%.out: %
%.c: %.w %.ch
%.tex: %.w %.ch
%:: %.v
%:: RCS/%,v
%:: RCS/%
%:: s.%
%:: SCCS/s.%

SOURCES = a.c b.c

# WORKAROUND: check for existence of files here
EXISTING_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCES))
MISSING_SOURCES = $(filter-out $(EXISTING_SOURCES),$(SOURCES))
ifneq "" "$(MISSING_SOURCES)"
$(error Missing source files: $(MISSING_SOURCES))
endif
# END WORKAROUND

OBJS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

DEPFILES = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.c.d)

EXE = a

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE)

$(DEPFILES): %.c.d : %.c
    @echo "Determining dependencies for $(<F)"
    @$(CC) -E -MM -MF$@ -MP $<

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling $(<F)"
    @$(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    @echo "Linking $(@F)"
    @$(CC) $+ -o $@

# This seems to be the troublemaking line!
-include $(DEPFILES)
```